# How to silent default juggernaut alert in firefox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, alert, juggernaut

I'm using the Juggernaut plugin in a rails application.

http://github.com/maccman/juggernaut_plugin

I can't find how to disable the alert() when running my app in Firefox.

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, what a shame... :-/

The helper must be like this: <%= juggernaut :debug => false %>